# Recursive Dependency Injection in LoginController

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5.5

I ran into an issue with the reflection of dependencies in my LoginController:

```
//LoginController

use App\Http\Controllers\Accounting;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use IssueTokenTrait;

    private $C_Account;

    public function __construct(Accounting\AccountsController $C_Account) 
    {   
    dd($C_Account);
    }
}
```

.

```
//AccountsController

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Accounting;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class AccountsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {

    }
}
```

When setting up my AccountsController that way, the Instance is correctly passed to the LoginController.

```
AccountsController {#190
 #middleware: []
}
```

## Next Step:

However, if I add a dependency to the AccountsController

```
//AccountsController

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Accounting;

use App\Http\Controllers\API\Accounting\AppAccountsController;

class AccountsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(
        AppAccountsController $C_AppAccount,
    ) {

    }
}
```

it throws a ReflectionException that AccountsController doesn't exists.

```
{
"message": "Class App\\Http\\Controllers\\Accounting\\AccountsController does not exist",
"exception": "ReflectionException",
"file": "/var/www/html/ideegoapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
"line": 811,
"trace": [
    {
//and so on
```

If I add another class-dependency (also with further dependencies in its constructor) to the LoginController everything works perfectly fine. The further dependencies will be resolved recursively.

What am I doing wrong here?

## UPDATE

In the end the AccountsController should look like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Accounting\DevicesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Payment\ProductsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Accounting\SubscriptionsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Accounting\AppAccountsController;

class AccountsController extends Controller
{

private $C_AppAccount;
private $C_Device;
private $C_Product;
private $C_Sub;

public function __construct(
    DevicesController $C_Device,
    ProductsController $C_Product,
    SubscriptionsController $C_Sub,
    AppAccountsController $C_AppAccount
) {
    $this->C_Device = $C_Device;
    $this->C_Product = $C_Product;
    $this->C_Sub = $C_Sub;
    $this->C_AppAccount = $C_AppAccount;
}
```

}

OK, I tried to create a new, clean controller and add each dependency step by step to see where the error occures. It does, when I add the AppAccountsController as dependency.
This controller has different dependencies in its own constructor.

```
public function __construct(
    CreditAccountsController $C_CreditAccount, 
    UserMetaController $C_UserMeta,
    BillDataController $C_BillData,
    AppAccount $model
) {
    //store injections in class-attributes
    $this->C_CreditAccount = $C_CreditAccount;
    $this->C_UserMeta = $C_UserMeta;
    $this->C_BillData = $C_BillData;

    //populate model if id is accessible
    if(defined('APP_ACCOUNT_ID')) {
        $this->model = $model::find(APP_ACCOUNT_ID);
    } else {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

The thing is, if I add the AppAccountsController as dependency to the LoginController, it is created successfully.
If I call the AccountsController directly from a route while it has all its dependencies in the constructor (even the AppAccountsController) it is perfectly created too.

The dependencies of the second level (AppAccountsController) have dependencies themself.
So overall I have a cascade of 3, (with the instantiating of the LoginController even 4) levels of dependencies to resolve.

Is this too much? Is there a limit?

Comment: Your first question: you import the class using different namespaces in example 1 and 2. If the first one works but not the second, I'd look there.

Comment: @JoelHinz could you explain that a bit more, please?
The namespace of the AccountsController and the use-statement in the LoginController are looking similar to me. Did I missed something?

Comment: I apologise, Danaq. I misread your question - please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: @JoelHinz No problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you injecting controllers into a controller?

Comment: Model controller? You mean like a resource controller?

Comment: @btl I decided to have two different types of controllers in this project. There are model-controllers, which contain the logic to get data of  models. And then there are controllers which hold the logic of interaction between different model-controllers.

Comment: For example: There are two different types of register for this application. The first one is just adding the user the database. But the second one needs to create many other records to create a "complete" user-account.
This logic is then needed even in the login process. If the user loggs in with an uncomplete account, those other records have to be created on login.
So I seperated the locig of basic-register from complete-register in an extra controller.

Comment: @btl Sorry, the lenght of the comment....
Yes, pretty much like this. I didn't used the -r option when creating them. I added a create-method manually. But I don't use the Route::resource-command because there are too many relations. I need extra logic for this.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION

I added this line to the constructor of the LoginController which in the first solution got the dependency passed. Now without dependency:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->C_Account = app()->make(AccountController::class);
}
```

Unfortunatly even with the the dependency like this:

```
public function __construct(AccountController $AAC) 
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout','refresh');
    $this->C_Account = $AAC;
}
```

It is again working. I don't know why.
I didn't get the shape of the error completely.
So maybe using the app()->make command added the class to the classmap or something in cached has changed.